# How to make the "style" of a google maps iframe look new

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe

I have the following iframe with google maps:
[image]

As you can see, google maps looks older here: square buttons and controls.
What I'd like to have is something like this:
[image]

A much better looking google maps. Round buttons and controls...

How do I create something like this? I've been trying to work around this, but without any success.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should consider using Google Maps Javascript API. It is not hard for basic use and it shows the controls the way you want.

Examples: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/?hl=en

Comment: The question is "How to make the "style" of a `google maps iframe` look new" this is not about iframe

Comment: @crg Although the title of the question mentions "iframe", if you read the question description you will realize that what Pedro Vieira wants is to display a newer (or at least newer in 2013) version of the Google Maps GUI.

At the moment of the reply this was achieved not by altering the iframe HTML element, but by using a different version of the API.

Answer (score 12):

```
<!-- Embed Google Maps Start -->
<iframe width="550" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=mesco,heuvelstraat 95,tilburg, nederland&layer=tc&t=m&z=18&source=embed&output=svembed"></iframe>
<!-- Embed Google Maps End -->
<!--Parameters:
---------------------
q= enter full address here or latitude+longitude e.g. (street name, city, county/state, country)
layer= (t = traffic | c = streetview | tc = both) - show map layer type
t= (m = normal map | k = satellite | h = hybrid | p = terrain) - Sets the kind of map shown
z= (1 - 23) - map zoom level. 23 value indicates fully zoomed in. (default is 18)
width= (value) - height of gmaps
height= (value) - width of gmaps-->
```

Answer (score 0):

For javascript API , you will need an API KEY .
Then you will have to choose a billing plan .

So i don't understand why you can directly pick the iframe from google maps for free on one side , and on the other side , you have to entrer credit card when you want to use the API directly.

Personally , i went back to the first option.
Very quick  to implement for basic use.