# Embed params in new Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, parameters, embed

The embed urls produced by the new version of google maps look like this:

[`https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m5!3m3!1m2!1s0x47b161837e1813b9%3A0x4263df27bd63aa0!2sHamburg%2C+Germany!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1385644179838`](https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m5!3m3!1m2!1s0x47b161837e1813b9%3A0x4263df27bd63aa0!2sHamburg%2C+Germany!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1385644179838)

How can I construct such a url programmatically given an address or latitude and longitude?

Comment: As @aemkei pointed out there's a pattern: /!(\d+)([a-z])([^!]*)/  
  
Which leads to this:  
https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=  
1 m 5  
3 m 3  
1 m 2  
1 s 0x47b161837e1813b9:0x4263df27bd63aa0  
2 s Hamburg,%20Germany  
5 e 0  
3 m 2  
1 s en  
2 s  
4 v 1385644179838

Comment: An answer like this would be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18382014/1491212
It seems there is no doc on the "iFrame oriented" API

Comment: No idea why this question would be closed, I'd like to know too, I think the question is very clear. Ah well.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if this is the new version or not:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

1. **Address**: Add a value following "q=" parameter (The Google Maps Embed API supports both + and %20 when escaping spaces.)
2. **Latitude and longitude**: "center=" parameter is for latitude and longitude, but you would
   also want to set "zoom=" level in order to present in the way how
   you want it to be displayed to users

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=pizza+pizza+oshawa&z=10&output=embed" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The magic here is `&output=embed`.

This is an example using 2 parameters. Replace `pizza+pizza+oshawa` with an url-encoded address and `10` with zoom level you want.

Comment: Update: now it must be https over http. Apart from that, this still works

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by kjdion84, the following works perfectly:

`<iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q='.$geolat.','.$geolng.'&t=k&z=16&output=embed" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`